# How to make visual interface in photoshop script?

Tags: photoshop-scripting

I'm wondering how to build visual interface for users using Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit.

What I mean is like Windows Forms application in Visual Studio, where we can have textbox, checkbox etc so that user can input data from that windows.

Is there such feature in ESTK, or if not is there any reference how to make one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: adobe has been a bit bad at deciding what technology to use or promote. earlier they wanted these to be made with flash, then they didt document it well. So they rolled the ScriptUI but never promoted that properly and now they are talking about html5 guis in panels, and again not documenting these. So its hard to go a head and make these tools. In anycase only the indesign script layer seems to be fully mature. With illustrator being complete crap in this regard. Ps they keep telling that the script gui is dead when i talk to them but give no good options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Adobe provides the ScriptUI component, which works with the ExtendScript JavaScript interpreter to
>   provide JavaScript scripts with the ability to create and interact with user interface elements.

See: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html for further info